# PC power cuts out ranomly

Tags: hardware-failure, desktop-computer

My PC power keeps cutting out. Sometimes after hours of being switched on and sometimes during booting. I've changed the PSU and the hard drive and after a while it starts happening again.

I've checked the connections inside the PC and double checked the 16gb of RAM is secure.

Comment: Have you looked into your Event Viewer at the system to see if there are any helpful logs of why your computer cuts  off.

Comment: I haven't but will give this a try. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll let you know how I get along.

Answer (score 0):

It is hardware failure. if you've checked PSU/HDD, it is very likely to be a motherboard or overheating issue.

I suggest to disconnect all other devices but CPU and RAM, start PC and pause it at BIOS stage. Wait until it gets shutdown. If so - it is faulty motherboard (often electrolytic capacitors fail).

Also you may verify RAM consistency using DOS program Memtest86+ to heavy load it for heating and stability.

Other way is to boot PC with Windows Live CD that runs from CD/DVD or USB stick so that HDD will be disconnected.